# Kibana : Visualization does not add floating values

Tags: elasticsearch, kibana, kibana-4, elasticsearch-2.0

Here is what i have in one of my columns

[image]

so, all of these values add up to 1.272. Now i tried to create a metric visualization for it but i get

[image]

why is it 0? The field is of type number in the index.

**Update**

So i tried to run this in sense

```
post indexName/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
        "sum block": {
          "sum": {
            "field": "blockSize"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

and i get

```
{
  "took": 4,
  "timed_out": false,
  "_shards": {
    "total": 5,
    "successful": 5,
    "failed": 0
  },
  "hits": {
    "total": 12,
    "max_score": 0,
    "hits": []
  },
  "aggregations": {
    "sum block": {
      "value": 0
    }
  }
}
```

why is this happening? Should it not add up the float values? also, in the index mapping

```
"blockSize": {
            "type": "long"
          }
```

shouldn't this be float or double? and if it is long, then why does it store a decimal point with the values?

Comment: Why dont you use float type?

Comment: the data coming in is float type. also, if its is being stored with decimal point, why does the aggregation not work?

Answer (score 2):

Probably that the first document that was indexed had `blockSize: 0` and thus the long type was chosen by ES to map that field. Now, float values are stored but 0 is indexed (since it's a long).

You need to wipe your index, correct the mapping and re-index your data.

Comment: thanks Val, but those are the only records in the data. None of the docs had blockSize of 0. also, i am using a template to create the mapping as i dont know how many fields i will get. Is there a way to force all numbers to be of float type?